# Colorize mesh according to the nodepoint colors

Tags: color, mesh

Given a set `p` of points (2D), each with a unique color `c`, I can mesh these points easily

```
p = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 2}];
c = Map[Hue[#] &, RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10]]; 
Show[DelaunayMesh[p],Graphics[Graphics[MapThread[{PointSize[.05], #1, Point[#2]} &, {c, p}]]]]
```

[image]

My question:

How can I easily colorize the lines and/or triangles according to the neighboring node colors?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify the rules? For instance, what color should the line between a blue and yellow dot be? How should a triangle face color be chosen, given the colors of its vertices?

Comment: @ MarcoB Along the line I would expect some blending.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
R = DelaunayMesh[p];
Graphics[
 GraphicsComplex[
  MeshCoordinates[R],
  MeshCells[R, 2, "Multicells" -> True],
  VertexColors -> c
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

## Edit

Getting colorgradients on the edges only seems to be somewhat trickier as `VertexCoordinate` for `Line` objects in a `GraphicsComplex` does not work. A workaround could be this:

```
elist = Flatten[MeshCells[R, 1, "Multicells" -> True][[1, 1]]];
Graphics[
 Line[
  Partition[MeshCoordinates[R][[elist]], 2],
  VertexColors -> Partition[c[[elist]], 2]
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome, Ulrich.

Comment: @ Henrik Where can I find information about the option `"Multicells" -> True`? In MMA v11.0.1.  it isn't known .

Comment: Nowhere. user21 once told me. _Very_ useful. Even the syntax highlighter of version 11.3 but it might work in version 11.0.1 already. If not, you may use `Polygon[MeshCells[R, 2][[All, 1]]]` instead (but it unpacks arrays and therefore may be slower for large meshes).

Comment: Again thank you for your useful help!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: @ Henrik Sorry for bugging you...Trying to apply your answer only for colored mesh lines I tried `Graphics[
 GraphicsComplex[
  MeshCoordinates[R],  MeshCells[R, 1   ]  , VertexColors -> c ]
 ] ` but MMA only returns  black meshlines. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Tricky, Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4):

```
SeedRandom[1]
p = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 2}];
c = Map[Hue[#] &, RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10]];
```

**1.** Post-process `MeshPrimitives` to add `VertexColors`:

```
rule = pr : (_Polygon | _Line | _Point) :> 
  Append[pr, VertexColors -> 
    AssociationThread[p, c] /@ First[pr /. Point[x_] :> Point[{x}]]]

Row[Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[5], AbsolutePointSize[12], 
     MeshPrimitives[DelaunayMesh[p], #] /. rule,
     AbsoluteThickness[3], Black, Circle[#, Offset[6]] & /@ p}, 
    ImageSize -> 300, PlotLabel -> Style[#, 16, Black]] & /@
 {0 | 1, 0 | 2, 0 | 1 | 2}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

**2.** Use the option `MeshCellShapeFunction` with desired styles/primitives for vertices, edges and faces:

```
Row[{DelaunayMesh[p, ImageSize -> 400,
   MeshCellStyle -> White,
   MeshCellShapeFunction ->
    {{0, All} -> ({c[[#3[[1, 1]]]], Disk[#, Offset[7]]} &),
     {1, All} -> ({AbsoluteThickness[7], CapForm["Round"], 
         Line[#, VertexColors -> c[[#3[[1, 1]]]]]} &),
     {2, All} -> None}],
  DelaunayMesh[p, ImageSize -> 400,
   MeshCellStyle -> White,
   MeshCellShapeFunction ->
    {{0, All} -> ({c[[#3[[1, 1]]]], Disk[#, Offset[7]]} &),
     {1, All} -> None,
     {2, All} -> ({EdgeForm[Gray], 
         Polygon[#, VertexColors -> c[[#3[[1, 1]]]]]} &)}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you're interested in doing this with 3D mesh objects (as I was) the following works in Mathematica 12.1:

```
mesh = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1], 
  MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 1}, PrecisionGoal -> 0.01] (* or any mesh object *)
vertexscalar = RandomReal[{0, 1}, Length[MeshCoordinates[mesh]]]

Graphics3D[
 GraphicsComplex[MeshCoordinates[mesh], 
  Polygon[MeshCells[mesh, 2][[All, 1]]], 
  VertexColors -> ColorData["DarkRainbow"] /@ Rescale[vertexscalar]]]
```

[image: a spherical mesh with the verticies randomly colored]